# Alternative to Iterrows() while looping through dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find an alternative to looping through a dataframe from a list of given column and replacing all the 'nan' which specific values that i want. Right now I'm using iterrows which is super slow, is there an alternative to this?

```
for i, row in target_df.iterrows():
                for j in missing_col_list:
                    if (j != 'raceeth' and j != 'schoolSize' and j != 'studentsInEnglish' and j !='minutesPerWeekEnglish'): 
                        if(str(row[j]) == 'nan'):
                                target_df.at[i,j] = 0.0
                        else:
                            target_df.at[i,j] = 1.0
```

Comment: Please share a sample of your dataframe with expected output for better understanding.

Comment: you can picture two columns dataframe and each column has some nan values, i just want to replace the nan values with 1s or 0s

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of columns that you want to fill the missing values in, you can do this:

```
cols = ['somecol1', 'somecol2']
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(0.0)
```

Comment: how would i fill it by rows ? I don't want to fill in the entire column all at once

Comment: @DavidLe what, **exactly** are you trying to do?

Comment: This will replace the nans in each column with the fill value while leaving the non-nan values as they were. There are also some other parameters for fillna that modify the behavior slightly. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

If the value you want to fill the nan with is dependent on the row in some non-trivial way, you're not going to do much better than iterrows.